# Recovery partition issue in SSD upgrade

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, ssd

I just upgraded my ASUS hard drive to SSD. The original hard drive was 1 TB and have
[the following partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imWUI.png). It has 2 primary partitions, one of 372.60 GB and 537.80 GB and 2 recovery partitions, one of 900 MB and one of 20 GB.

After I cloned the data to SSD, the partition becomes [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5xSY.png). The 900 MB recovery partition is still there, but the 20 GB recovery partition is gone. The total size of Data (D:) partition is 99.22 GB, the files content are about 50 GB and the free space is around 30 GB. It seems that the 20 GB recovery partition is inside this Data partition but I can't see it in File Explorer.

How important are these recovery partitions? Do I need to reclone and make sure the recovery partitions are there? Any recommendation on which software I can use for that (I used Samsung Data Migration)?
If it's not needed, how can I release this 20 GB from my Data partition?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Recovery partition is used to restore your operating system when there is failure or crash in your operating system. So, That is important.

Comment: But if I have created a recovery media already, can i delete these recovery partitions?